# Fastest solution to compute normal

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex, normals

A physics engine return a deformed mesh (only geometry vertices). 
I take this mesh to render the geometry (~500000 vertices).
What is the fastest solution and the least expensive to compute normal vertices every frame?
OpenCL? Geometry Shaders? In a CPU thread? Other?

Comment: then what are you going to do with it? is this a typical object in your game (I really really hope not if you want to calculate the whole thing every frame, and not just store it)? how often will this object be "deformed"?

Comment: It's on a medical simulation. The object is deformed every frame. I need normals for rendering the mesh.

Comment: I will assume that you mean vector, and not actual vertices (I do not know what that would even mean). find all faces (determine adjacent points). for each face take any 3 points on the face, and create 2 vectors (V1=p1-p2, V2=p1-p3) then take their cross product. keep in mind that if your camera is right, and nothing shows up try reversing your cross product this will give you a vector normal to the plane of the face. rinse, and repeat for each face. seriously try with a pyramid, or cube first

Comment: Yes but it's not too long on CPU ?

Comment: is that an actual question, or a statement? (I will go with question) the most complex part will be determining where the faces are (this is the big problem with collision detection on complex-convex polyhedrons), and once that is done constructing 2 vectors, and doing a cross product is relatively trivial.

Comment: @urza57 you might be able to do it with a geometry shader that returns the same number of primitive.

Comment: Possibly try the geometry shader if available.. shaders are faster than Cuda/OpenGL since you don't have to pass a buffer to them from a memory region on the GPU to another like you would do in GPGPU approaches.

Comment: Geometry shader is definitely the best idea.  Just want to throw in that if that doesn't work out, you're going to want to try to incorporate a mesh adjacency data structure such as Half-Edge or Split-Edge.  These will greatly help speed up the runtime of computing normals on the CPU.

Comment: I wonder if there is value in bringing normals in from the modeling app, then:
If you are spending time deforming (manipulating) some of the vertices each frame, why not transform the affected vertex normal by the same transformation? That way, instead of recalculating all normals each frame, simply transform the affected ones by the same transformation you applied to the vertex.

Comment: This question cannot be answered as asked. What the "fastest solution" is will vary wildly with hardware and implementations. Not to mention that, regardless of what you're coming up with, you'll have to stream 500k+ vertices per frame. The best you can do is try out several techniques and benchmark them. That being said, are you sure your physics system can't be made to spit out normals? It must have most of the information needed to generate them when it does its deformation.

Comment: @ktodisco: You want a shader to sample arbitrarily into an array of connected vertices to compute a vertex normal? I can't say that this is the most parallel-friendly activity. Sure, the inputs have one output, but vertex shaders would be terrible at it (you can't use attribute inputs at all), geometry shaders don't have a complex enough topography to do it (and they'd be no better than vertex shaders ultimately), etc. Shaders are generally meant for rendering; while they can do this, I wouldn't expect them to be the fastest thing at it.

Comment: @NicolBolas You're absolutely right, the geometry shader could only work for flat shading, since it lacks the complexity and data access to do normal smoothing.  My suggestions of the Adjacency Data Structures were for CPU, not the shader.

Comment: Definitely GS.  Don't even think about doing it on the CPU - you'll get poor parallelism, a lot of extra code on a processor that's not well-suited to running that kind of code, and will still have to deal with re-uploading the data to the GPU every frame (which will add extra bottlenecks of it's own).

Answer (score 3):

A lot of this depends if you need interpolated normals over the polygon or can live with a the 'faceted look' of per-triangle normals.

The per-triangle normals are a lot easier to compute: a simple cross prod of the three vertices with one of them being made a local-origin by subtracting it from the other two first.

Smooth per-vertex require finding all the triangles that share a vertex, and averaging their per-triangle normals, by weighting their angle by some factor, typically the angle of the corner made at the vertex for that triangle.

If your mesh can have an arbitrary number of triangles meeting in a corner this can be rather difficult implement on a GPU.

Answer (score 0):

So I coded simple C++ test program that calculates normal for pair of vectors using cross product 500000 times. Source highlights are:

```
struct Vector3
{
  float x, y, z;

  Vector3();
};

const int n = 500000;

Vector3 a[n], b[n], c[n];

void CalculateNormals()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  {
    c[i].x = a[i].y * b[i].z - a[i].z * b[i].y;
    c[i].y = a[i].z * b[i].x - a[i].x * b[i].z;
    c[i].z = a[i].x * b[i].y - a[i].y * b[i].x;
  }
}
```

I've executed 1000 passes on random data. And average time of `CalculateNormals()` function to finish is `3.11` ticks. So I think the idea to calculate this stuff on CPU is straithforward and efficient. By the way my CPU is `Intel Core i5-2400 @ 3.10 GHz`.

Comment: Interpolation between triangle normals also needs to be done in order to get smooth shading.  The cross-product approach will only give flat shading.

Comment: @iodiot the result vectors are not normalized!

Comment: @iodiot a few things `a`, and `b` should be determined for the current face not just given as values, and could very well be static to the current iteration of the for loop. And, `500000` was not the face count it was the number of vertices (the number of faces will be some fraction of the number of vertices, and typically higher)

Comment: @Maik Semder Normal attached to the vertex can be normalized trivially in vertex shader. Sorry I forgot about this, cause was surprised by CPU performance.

Comment: @iodiot no problem. However, it would be good to update the post, measure the timing including normalizing.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at implementing it in either OpenCL or CUDA. A lot of medical applications are going towards that field because of the insane amount of data they have to process per frame.

The problem you have should be easy to parallelize (run on the multiple cores of a videocard). You have a fixed input (three vertices) and a fixed output (one normal). So, a version of the program could be:

- Physics simulation deforms the mesh.
- Upload data to OpenGL using vertex buffers.
- Lock buffers for OpenCL processing.
- OpenCL writes to normal buffer, keeping everything in video memory.
- Unlock buffers for OpenGL usage.
- Rendering using vertex data with normals.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this on the CPU with indexed meshes and I'm assuming smooth vertex normals, then the fastest way I've come up with is:

1. Make sure polygon->vertex access is cache-friendly. This makes a world of difference if you minimize cache misses here. You can look at Tom Forsythe's [Linear-Speed Vertex Cache Optimization](https://tomforsyth1000.github.io/papers/fast_vert_cache_opt.html) as a start.
2. If the mesh is super high res like millions of vertices, it might take too long to do these vertex cache optimizations and their results might not be so great. In that case, split your big mesh into multiple smaller sub-meshes with special handling of the vertices at the boundary of each sub-mesh to produce seamless results. That will also allow you to do these vertex cache optimizations in parallel.
3. Use fast SIMD inverse square root if you're okay with an approximation of the normal like `rsqrtps`.
4. This is a little bit dirty and could lead to noticeable artifacts if you aren't careful but sometimes you can delay the normal computations and do them in parallel/async with deforming objects without the user noticing. This way you might deform the mesh for a few iterations before you update the normals once. Now I'm not sure if this would be acceptable for a game engine. I'm coming at this from the VFX side of the industry when users do things like sculpt deformations on meshes with 10 million polygons (and not necessarily triangles). I've found in those cases at least that you can be sneaky and not update the normals necessarily with every single frame rendered and get away with it, using a separate thread for updating normals which tends to lag a frame or two behind the deformations.